# OpenSSL-1.0.1e for RHEL 5

Tags: linux, openssl, rpmbuild, rhel5

I was trying to build OpenSSL-1.0.1e for RHEL5 platform.

I got few file not found errors from rpmbuild, after further analysis i found that package builder was searching for libssl.so.10 and libcrypto.so.10. But, the actual files created were libssl.so.6 and libcrypto.so.6.

So, i have replaced the soversion macro with 6 instead of 10.

The package building was successful.

Is there any issues replacing the library version number for latest openssl with 6 instead of 10 in RHEL5 platform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any interfaces have been removed going from `.6` to `.10`, it is very possible that it breaks applications requiring a symbol that existed in the actual `.6` but not in your `.10` renamed to `.6`. Read [1] for more information about sonames.

In any case, this is definitely bad practice and should be avoided. If you have an application which requires a newer version of OpenSSL than what comes with RHEL5, I'd rather just bundle the newer libraries with your application and use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to have the directory containing the bundled libraries be searched before the system directores.

- [1] http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Updating-version-info.html